# Powerpoint 2010 VBA code randjump no repeat slides

Tags: vba, random, powerpoint

I am trying to find a code which allows me to use a macro to jump to a random slide between a range without repeating until the end of the show. I have the code for the random jump, but I am getting repeats. This is the code I have used. I just want to know how I can adjust it to have no repeats. There are 57 slides and I want to randomize from 12 to 57.

```
Sub randjump ()
Randomize
Dim Inum as Integer
Inum = Int(57 * Rnd + 12)
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (Inum)
Do
oColl.Add "Slide", CStr(Inum)
Loop
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possibly: as you jump to each slide, add its index (your Inum) to a collection: oColl.Add "Slide", Cstr(Inum).  This will throw an error if the index has already been added. Do it in a loop, trap the error if it occurs and keep looping, or exit the loop if no error.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg. Thank you for the advice. I am very new to coding. I tried adding your suggestion like this                                                         Sub randjump()
Randomize
Dim Inum As Integer
Inum = Int(57 * Rnd + 12)
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (Inum)
Do
oColl.Add "Slide", CStr(Inum)
Loop
End Sub                                                                                                                                                                                                               But unfortunately to no effect.

Comment: It's best if you edit your original post to reflect the modifications you've made to it so we can see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: Noted. I edited the original post to reflect the current iteration of the code. I still get repeats.

Comment: You need to do Static oColl as New Collection to dim the collection as static so it doesn't go out of scope between calls to the subroutine. You need to check to see whether the slide number is in the collection already before jumping to it.